# Add email regular expression to Sitefinity Registration widget

Tags: asp.net, regex, email, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

Does anyone know how to add an email regular expression to Sitefinity's Registration Widget?

I'm new to both Sitefinity and regular expressions, but I'd like to restrict users registering to a specific email address domain during registration, with something like this:

```
^[\w\-\.\+]+\@\b\.\mydomain\b\.\bcom\b$
```

Which I think might exclude all but @mydomain.com email addresses.  If that works, I need to find the right place to put it.

Comment: The word boundaries are not necessary (and in fact hurtful because `@\b\.` can never match). Use `^[\w.+-]+@mydomain\.com$` instead. No idea where to put a regex in Sidefinity, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. First download [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)
2. Decompile the Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.dll
3. Under the advanced setting of the Registration widget look at the "LayoutTemplatePath" field and locate that resource file in just decompile (in SF5.4 it is "Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.Templates.Frontend.Security.RegistrationForm.ascx" might differ a bit in SF4
4. Copy the widget code from JustDecompile
5. Create a new .ascx in VisualStudio or your choice
6. Add a Regex validator for the email text box
7. Register your widget in sitefinity in the admin area

As a last alternative you could use jQuery to check that field. use `

```
var emRegEx = \^[\w.+-]+@mydomain\.com$\;
$("form").submit(function(){
   if(emRegEx.test($("textboxID Or Class").val())){
      $("textboxID Or Class").before("<div style='color:red;'>Email Denied</div>");
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
});
```